# Black image after clipping with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, clip, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to clip my tif image but i got it readable only in arcgis, and when i open the folder where it is recorded i found it black and cannot open it or read it with Autocad ..
what do you think about ?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and made the commande Spatial analys ==> Extraction ==> Extract by Mask

I tried also  Data Management tools ==> Raster ==> Raster processing ==> Clip

But the both give the same result.

Comment: What do you see when you use "Identify"tool on the raster? Is there a value in Info window or just NULL?

Comment: oh thank you faith i got it it was just a sample fault